# Conditional row dragging in Aggrid reactjs

Tags: drag-and-drop, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**Setup Summary**: We have two aggrids where we drag from one grid to the second grid. This works perfectly.

**Issue**: We have some lines we don't want to enable drag on. So we want a conditional drag based on a cell value.

Currently our table settings (we use reactjs) are as follows:

Table 1 and 2 have these properties:

```
rowData={rowData}
ref={fileGridRef}
columnDefs={columnDefs}
gridOptions={gridOptions}
rowDragManaged={true}
rowDragEntireRow={true}
animateRows={true}
onRowDragEnd={(params: any) => addToFilesGrid(params)}
suppressClickEdit={true}
```

gridOptions are (for both grids)

```
rowSelection: "single",
rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
```

Column defs are (for both grids)

```
    {
        field: "name",
        headerName: "File Name",
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        editable: true,
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center", marginLeft: "-10px" },
        cellRenderer: EditCellRenderer,
        rowDrag: (params: any) => {
            params.data.type !== "";       //HERE IS THE CONDITION WE HAVE 
        },
    },
    {
        field: "type",
        headerName: "Type",
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        editable: false,
    }
```

When the params.data.type is "" we want it not to move.
I tried playing around with rowDragManaged=false, but then nothing moved. I thought about making handlers for onDragEnter/Leave/Move/End, but I would rather avoid that if I can.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Do I have to do unmanaged dragging if I want this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution!

I had seen that **rowDrag** could be set to a **conditional** statement but had issues getting it working, and there is one example on ag-grid docs that wasn't helpful in my use case.

So, I have a table, and if a cell is *BLANK* I don't want the row to drag.

So in the ColDef I had:

```
rowDrag: params => params.data.type === "",
```

Because that is what it was in the rowData. Also when I printed out params in other row changing functions (onRowSelected, onRowDragMove, etc...) this field was an empty string -> "".

It seems like for this conditional however it may be treated as an *undefined* or have a *space*. Not exactly sure, but I was able to do this:

```
params => params.data.type.length > 1,
```

And it worked! This leads me to believe the  tags in the aggrid cell or something in their code inserts a space *somewhere*.

This was shown when I tried

```
rowDrag: params => params.data.type.length > 0,
```

and I could still drag the rows where my type field was "".